# How to pass class name to sub menu item in wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add class name to sub menu ul

wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) );

Comment: There is no default way to do that; you would have to create your custom nav walker function for that. But _why_ do you want this in the first place, what is the desired end result you want to achieve? If you just want to format those items differently - that most likely won’t need an additional/different class here, but only proper use of selectors in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace class

```
    <?php 
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => 'primary-menu',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => '',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => '',
    'menu_id'         => 'primary-menu',
    'echo'            => false,
    'fallback_cb'     => '',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          =>''
);
// your class name : like menu_sub
echo str_replace('sub-menu', 'menu_sub', wp_nav_menu( $defaults)
);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, I believe this will be helpful for you. wp_nav_menu filter should help you doing so or there are other filters `wp_nav_menu_items` and `wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items` those should help you. Visit [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) for more information.

```
function new_submenu_class($menu) {    
    $menu = preg_replace('/ class="sub-menu"/','/ class="yourclass" /',$menu);        
    return $menu;      
}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu','new_submenu_class');
```

or extend `Walker_Nav_Menu` class and override `start_lvl()` .